# Sum of columns of a dynamically generated gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, aspxgridview

I need to get the sum of  the cells of a gridview in the footer.
The `GridView` is generated dynamically and then displayed on a webpage.
i am able to get the sum of any column if specified by `cellId`, but when i am trying to apply for loop, it is not working..

This is what i have done so far..

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)  
{  
}  
else  
{  
    for (int i = 18; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)  
    {  
     //  e.Row.Cells[i].Text = e.Row.Cells[i].Text.Trim().Replace("&nbsp;", "0").Replace("amp;", "0");  
         total[i] += Convert.ToDouble(e.Row.Cells[i].Text);  
    }  
}
```

18 is the number of column from where onwards the sum will be calculated.
commented line is already placed so that no null or blanks are there....

Comment: It is not working? You got an exception or the code do not give you what you should have? Can't you do a foreach loop instead? `Foreach( Cell in e.Row.Cells)` or something like this?

Comment: foreach cell will traverse through each cell of row, and there are columns with strings and other data types too..

Comment: and there is no error or exception.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what actual problem you had, however, why don't you use `DataControlRowType.Footer` instead and this little LINQ query:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
{
    double cellValue = 0;
    double sum = e.Row.Cells.Cast<TableCell>().Skip(18)
        .Where(cell => double.TryParse(cell.Text, out cellValue))
        .Sum(cell => cellValue);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but will appreciate if u can show the problem in the code.and the logic behind your code, as i have not used LINQ...
sorry if i offended, but i m trying to learn things...

Comment: @humorousdragon: does this  work after all? What don't you understand, the LINQ query or why this should work instead of your approach? You are not using the footer but the data-rows because of `if(header){}else{//now the datarows are following}`.

Comment: i simply copied it and used..but it did not work..it is not throwing any exception though..but no result so far..
And i have not been able to sum the data column to display in footer, using any method...

Answer (score 0):

after a bit of work i figured out...thanks for showing me the right direction...

```
    if (GridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        int TtlRows = GridView1.Rows.Count;
        int TtlCol = GridView1.Rows[0].Cells.Count;
        int FxdCol = 1;
        int ComputedCol = TtlCol - FxdCol;

        for (int i = FxdCol; i < TtlCol; i++)
        {
            double sum = 0.000;

            for (int j = 0; j < TtlRows; j++)
            {
                sum += GridView1.Rows[j].Cells[i].Text != "&nbsp;" ? double.Parse(GridView1.Rows[j].Cells[i].Text) : 0.000;
            }
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
            {
                e.Row.Cells[i].Text = sum.ToString("#0.000");
            }

        }  
    }
```